# Can a nuclear reactor withstand a missile attack?

Tags: safety, reinforced-concrete

Because of the war in Ukraine I am interested in the question if a nuclear reactor is designed to withstand a missile attack.

In university, back in the eighties, we were assured that a nuclear reactor would withstand an airplane crash, such as a Boeing 747 Jumbo Jet. But perhaps a Russian war missile has much more destructive power? Or is 1 meter of reinforced concrete invulnerable for a stupid missile?

I understand that my question is a bit vague, especially because as an electrical engineer I don't have any expertise on concrete, but these days this question is pretty relevant.

Comment: It would most likely depend on the explosive strength of the warhead on the missiles & how many missiles hit the reactor. Direct hits from [bunker buskers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunker_buster) or nuclear weapons would be very problematic.

Comment: Drop a grand slam - that’ll shift it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [published article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312646179_Integrated_Blast_Resistance_Model_of_Nuclear_Power_Plant_Auxiliary_Facilities) which provides a detailed analysis of damage levels vs. plant design vs. attack type (which bomb/missile, etc).  Here's the citation and abstract:

Brandys, Irad & Ornai, David & Yigal, Ronen. (2017). Integrated Blast Resistance Model of Nuclear Power Plant Auxiliary Facilities. Journal of Nuclear Engineering and Radiation Science. 3. 10.1115/1.4035692.

> Standards, guidelines, manuals and researches, refer mainly to the
> required protection of a nuclear power plant (NPP) containment
> structure (where the reactor's vessel is located) against different
> internal and external extreme events. However, there is no
> consideration regarding the man-made extreme event of external
> explosion resulting from air bomb or cruise missile. A novel
> Integrated Blast Resistance Model (IBRM) of NPP's reinforced concrete
> (RC) auxiliary facilities due to an external above ground explosion
> based on two components is suggested. The first is structural dynamic
> response analysis to the positive phase of an external explosion based
> on the single degree of freedom (SDOF) method combined with spalling
> and breaching empirical correlations. The second is in-structure shock
> analysis, resulted from direct-induced ground shock and air-induced
> ground shock. As a case study, the resistance of Westinghouse
> commercial NPP AP1000 control room, including a representative
> equipment, to an external explosion of Scud B-100 at various stand-off
> distances ranging from 250m (far range) till contact, was analyzed.
> The structure's damage level is based on its front wall supports'
> angle of rotation and the ductility ratio. Due to the lack of specific
> structural damage demands and equipment's dynamic capacities, common
> protective structures standards and manuals are used while requiring
> that no spalling nor breaching shall occur as well as remaining in the
> elastic regime. The IBRM may be used in wider researches concerning
> other NPP's auxiliary facilities and systems based upon their
> specifications.

I think it's equally important to recognize that  nuclear plants are required to support multi-level safe shutdown sequences in response to all sorts of damage or subsystem failures.

Comment: Great info. Seems like the conclusion is: currently it is unknown if a nuclear power plant can withstand a missile attack.

Answer (score 3):

The design specifications between different plants might be different -- however I doubt there is in many (if any) a design specification that states "withstand impact of X kilotonnes TNT in outer walls of reactor".

I suspect that implicitly is mostly covered by earthquake specifications, and the ***implicit (and possible erroneous) assumption***  that nobody is stupid enough to willfully target a nuclear reactor.

Comment: I agree about the stupid factor, but the kilotonnes would apply to an atomic bomb. I would believe that nothing can protect against that, and was just wondering about conventional rocket attacks, as is the case now in Ukraine

Comment: you are right "kilo tonnes" was an exaggeration on my part (most missiles are in the order of tonnes). I subconsciously used that to highlight the stupidity factor - because anyone stupid enough to direct a conventional missile, would not be far off from pointing a nuclear warhead.

Answer (score 1):

A missile hit would not have to pierce the outer containment structure in order to wreck the reactor. All it would need to do is shock the structure hard enough to crack open the coolant pipes leading from the primary cooling loop to the secondary. Such a shock would probably be strong enough to disable all the emergency electrical control systems and shear the turbogenerators off their mountings.

Comment: The question then is: would the explosion from a rocket missile shock the structure more than a Jumbo Jet crash? The mass of a 1 meter thick concrete containment building would be huge, and the entire plant is designed to withstand earthquakes. My conclusion from your reasoning would be that a missile would NOT endanger the plant.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problems would be loss of instrumentation and control.

Comment: This is not an answer